# GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT regenerating which memory?

Tags: opengl, libgdx

This is the code that probably all libgdx apps have:

```
Gdx.gl.glClearColor( 1, 0, 0, 1 );
Gdx.gl.glClear( GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
```

or

```
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

This sets the color with witch the screen will be flushed(first line) and than flush it(second line). But what is the meaning of the `GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT`? From the docs I got that GL is an interface wrapping all the methods of OpenGL ES 2.0 and it is there so I can call methods. The meaning of `GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT` is puzzling to me. It should regenerate memory currently enabled for color writing... Does it mean that it would erase all images? Will it erase ShapeRenderer objects? Is anything on the screen that isn't part of color writing and will not be erased when this constant is used? Does GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT erases the Z-position of textures?

Comment: Passing `GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT` to `glClear` clears the color buffer. Passing `GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT` clears the depth buffer. There's also a `GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT` which - you guessed it - clears the stencil buffer. You can also bitwise-or them together to clear multiple buffers at a time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you draw things on the screen you dont draw them directly. Instead they are first drawn to a so called "back-buffer". This is a block of memory (a buffer) that contains four bytes for every pixel of the screen, one byte for each color component (red, green, blue and alpha) of each pixel. When you are ready drawing (when your render method finishes) this buffer is presented at once on the screen.

The existing value of the buffer is important. For example when you draw an image on the screen and then draw a semi transparent image on top of that, then the result is a mix of the two images. The first image is drawn to the back-buffer causing the memory of the back-buffer to contain the pixel data of that image. Next the second image is drawn and is blended on top of the existing data of the back-buffer.

Each byte of the block of memory always has a value, e.g. 0 for black, 255 for white, etc. Even if you havent drawn anything to the buffer it has to have some value. Calling `glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)` instructs the GPU to fill the entire back buffer with some specified value (color). This value can be set using the call to `glClearColor`. Note that you don't have to call `glClearColor` each time `glClear` is called, the driver will remember the previous value.

Besides the back-buffer for the color values of the screen (the color buffer), the GPU can have other type of buffers, one of which is the depth buffer. This is again a block of memory of a few bytes per pixel, but this time it contains a depth value for each pixel. This makes it possible, e.g. when 3D rendering, to make sure that objects which are behind other objects are not being drawn. This buffer needs to be cleared using `GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT`.

Note that you can clear both of them together using a bitwise or operation: `Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);`

In practice, calling `glClear` should be the first thing you do in your render method (or when binding a FBO for example). This is because it tells the driver that you don't care about the existing values of the buffer. This allows the driver to do optimizations because it doesn't have to reconstruct (copy) the original memory block.